# Is it possible to embed html in a ternary in angular expression?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need different buttons with icon and text depending on the user.id but the html seems not to be interpreted in a ternary in an angular expression

I can have the result I want with a ngIf and two separated buttons but it would be better to do it in one line of code.

```html
{{ 
  user.id ? 
  '<i class="far fa-save"></i>Save' : 
  '<i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>Add' 
}}
```

the expected result is having one icon and the corresponding text, for instance: ICON-ADD Add.
Instead of that, I have the entire expression: "user.id ? 'ICON-SAVE Save' : 'ICON-ADD Add'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary for inner text and `ngClass` to toggle classes as following:

```
<i class="far" [ngClass]="{'fa-save' : user.id, 'fa-plus-quare': !user.id}">
    {{user.id ? 'Save' : 'Add'}}
</i>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using ***ngIf**:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user.id"> <i class="far fa-save"></i>Save </ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!user.id"> <i class="far faplus-square"></i>Add </ng-container>
```

Using **Ternary Operator**

```
<ng-container>
    <i [ngClass]="user.id ? 'far fa-save' : 'far faplus-square'"></i>
      {{user.id ? 'Save' : 'Add'}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: If you don't want to introduce redundant nodes in DOM, you can use `ng-container` instead of a real element like `span`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngif with else clause, here's the documentation:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

In your case it'd look like that:

```
<i class="far fa-save" *ngIf='user.id; else showAdd'>Save</i>
<ng-template #showAdd>
    <i class="far fa-plus-square">Add</i>
</ng-template>
```